# Is it possible to call an .EXE file from an .ASM code to run without an OS?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, exe

So here I have an `.EXE` file that runs in full-screen, and I need to call it from `.ASM` language. To make it more clear, I am trying to make an OS prototype (idk if it makes me sound mad), where I have an `.EXE` file that I need to call from an `.ASM` code. I am a learner, so I am not sure if this is possible, but according to other answers on the net, I would have to make a ***basic I/O subsystem, memory management, and stuff*** *(which an OS typically does)*. I would like to have an example where an `.EXE` while is called from `.ASM` code, and the `.EXE` is executed.

Thank You!, even if you only read this :)

And if you need the .EXE file with its components, I can provide you that, if you can help me...

Comment: You will have to provide all the parts of an OS used by the executable to be able to run it.

Comment: That's sort of how the old Nintendo games work. Each game pack is kind of an OS by itself.

Comment: Ok! So can I call an .exe from an .asm in the first place? If not, what else can I do to load an .exe without an OS?

Comment: @Kshitij `.exe` is just one possible executable format. You can write your own OS to support running `.exe`. BTW, someone can write a full book to answer your question. https://wiki.osdev.org/ is a great quality resource.

Comment: The normal thing would be for your OS to provide a system call that takes a path to an executable as an argument.  Like POSIX `execve(char *path, char *argv[], char *envp[])` that replaces the current process (usually used after `fork`), or like Windows `CreateProcess` that's like fork+exec.  Then your kernel includes a program-loader for whatever executable file-format you choose to use for it.  (ELF, PE32 exe, and MachO64 are the common ones in existing use).  So yes you'd have to write it.  Obviously the code in the executable needs to work under your OS; it won't run Windows .exes easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most `.EXE` files use operating system services and won't work if these services are not provided. More specific: A DOS `.EXE` files requires the DOS APIs, e.g. INT 21h to be present. The most prominent operating system service used by application programs is the file system driver. The code in the `.EXE` file asks the operating system to *open a file called DATA.BIN*, and it's up to the operating system to locate the file on the disk. You can not run a `.EXE` file that tries to access files without any kind of operating system.

If you are writing your own operating system, you either have to implement a way to load a DOS kernel (e.g. MS-DOS, FreeDOS) from your operating system so the `.EXE` file can access the system services it requires, or your operating system needs to implement DOS-compatible services. Loading and executing an `.EXE` file is a straight-forward task (assuming you already have file access working). You load the header first. The header indicates the start of the executable code/data inside the EXE file and the size of it. You have to load that area, and finally you need to load the relocations (size and length of the relocation table is also included in the EXE header), and apply the relocations before setting the stack to the address requested in the EXE header and jumping to the entry point.

If you loaded a DOS kernel into your operating system, the DOS kernel already implements loading and executing EXE files, so you could just delegate the process of loading/starting to the DOS kernel by calling int 21h/AX=4B00h.